# How to send a Post request from volley while the user is entering text in the edittext?

Tags: android, json

I am having an edittext and I want to populate a autocomplete textview from the response received from server but not able to see how to send the request through volley when user have just entered 3 or 4 characters.As 3 characters are entered I have to make the request and show the response as autocomplete.He then clicks on the suggestion and then accurate result is shown.

```
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String searchText = e1.getText().toString().trim();
            if (searchText.length()>3){

                request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, suggesturl + e1.getText().toString(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hii",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        try {

                            JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject obj1 = array1.getJSONObject(i);
                                id = obj1.getString("Title");
                                t1.setText(id);
                                //getdetails(id);

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Citydetails.error();


                    }


                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hashMap.put("cityName", city);
                        return hashMap;
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextWatcher` -

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //You can check the number of characters entered and make your API request
              String searchText = editText.getText().toString().trim();
               if(searchText.length > 3 ){ //Any number you want
                    //Make request here
              }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Nothing happening I think the GET request is not being sent.